# bcrypt error while trying to import pysftp or paramiko

Tags: python, bcrypt, pysftp

I'm trying to use pysftp on python, although pysftp is installed I get a Bcrypt ImportError

So I uninstalled and re-installed bcrypt, checked the location of the directory spyder is referring to for importing packages, bcrypt exists. Also checked that the   **init.py** file exists . Checked inside the **init.py** file that the module _bcrypt exists. Even tried importing bcrypt separately.

import bcrypt
import pysftp

import pysftp
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import pysftp

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pysftp__init__.py", line 12, in 
    import paramiko

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\paramiko__init__.py", line 22, in 
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 90, in 
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ed25519key.py", line 17, in 
    import bcrypt

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\bcrypt__init__.py", line 25, in 
    from . import _bcrypt

ImportError: cannot import name '_bcrypt' from 'bcrypt' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\bcrypt__init__.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled Anaconda , and there was no issue. The actual solution is still not found.